# prep for exam CEH V8

Tags: professional-education

I study for CEH V8 exam and I want to know is any list of questions or something? An example for the exam, how does this look like? I found just this: http://www.thelonecoder.com/pdfs/CEH-practise-312-50.pdf but this is old a bit, because the first question is Netware Server which is an old technology, am I wrong? and I found also this: https://scadahacker.com/library/Documents/Cheat_Sheets/Hacking%20-%20CEH%20Cheat%20Sheet%20Exercises.pdf but this si for CEH V6, so any idea what other resources is outside the material?

Comment: EC Council has details on the exam. Please check with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic google search tip which will help you. If you want to search for materials that would help you in preparing for an examination just narrow down the search to *.edu domains (educational sites)

So in your case, you want to search for CEH related materials. Search like:
`"Certified ethical hacker" site:edu` OR `"CEH v8" site:edu`

Get CCNA related materials like this - `"CCNA" site:edu`

Happy Googling!
Cloud is the new limit :-)